# Erro Ponteiro para ponteiro em c++!

Tags: c++, matriz

Criei uma classe Matrix, para manipular uma matriz. Na declaração da classe tenho os seguintes membros (publicos):

```
class Matrix{
public:
    unsigned char **mat; //ponteiro para ponteiro de uchar
    int nRows; //numero de linhas
    int nCols; //numero de colunas da matriz
    Matrix(int nRows, int nCols); //construtor
    void putColumn(int *Col, int j); //metodo para adicionar colunas à matriz
}
```

No construtor inicializo o nRows e nCols e aloco memória para mat.

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
//Construtor da classe que recebe número de linhas e número de colunas.
{
    nRows = rows;
    nCols = cols;
    mat = (unsigned char**)malloc(nRows*nCols*sizeof(unsigned char));
}
```

Os indices da matriz dispõem-se ao longo da memória sequencialmente, como se tivessemos um array, e para aceder aos mesmos seria algo do tipo:

```
unsigned char * p; 
p = mat[i] + j*nRows;//onde i = linha e j =coluna
```

Depois tenho um método para adicionar colunas à matriz:

```
void Matrix::putColumn(int *Col, int j)
{
    unsigned char *p;
    p = *mat + j*nRows;//j é a coluna que pretendo adicionar
    //ou seja, coluna 1, 2, 3, 4 até completar a matriz
    memcpy(p,Col,nCols);
}
```

Na função main após criar um objecto Matrix, adiciono uma coluna à matriz:

```
unsigned char *col;
col = (unsigned char*) malloc(nlinhas*sizeof(unsigned char));

for ( int i = 1; i <= nlinhas; i++){
    col[i] = i;
}
matrix.putColumn(col,0);
```

O problema aqui é que ao executar esta função (main) no método putColumn da Matrix obtenho o seguinte erro: Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcdcd.
Agradecia se alguém me pudesse ajudar, obrigado!

Comment: Você está programando meio em C e meio em C++. Deveria escolher um estilo e ficar com ele. COmo está usando o C++ não deveria usar `malloc`, `memcpy`, ponteiros brutos e coisas do tipo. Mesmo em C não deveria fazer *cast* no `malloc`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/221800. Eu tenho dificuldade de achar erros genéricos em códigos cheio de ponteiros só olhando para ele. Seria interessante debigar e passar melhores informações ou melhor ainda, postar algo que possamos executar e ver o que está acontecendo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Fora que vc está misturando tipos. A sua "matrix" é criada a partir de `unsigned char` mas quando você insere colunas você usa `int`. Em uma arquitetura de 32bits o `unsigned char` vai ter 1 byte e o `int` 4 bytes...

Comment: @Luiz Vieira Mesmo ao inserir colunas uchar continua a dar erro, por isso deduzi que o problema não viesse dai.

Comment: Bom, eu não sei qual é o problema principal, mas inserir colunas de inteiros em algo alocado como char vai dar erro também. :)

Comment: Outra coisa que está "estranha": você aloca a nova coluna multiplicando por `nlinhas` (que, aliás, não devia ser `nRows`?), mas o `memcpy` usa (corretamente) `nCols`. Parece que você devia alocar a nova coluna a partir de `nCols`.

Comment: @bigown        Eu sei que estou a misturar as linguagens, mas é intencional. Penso que o cast do malloc seja obrigatório para c++. Ao fazer debug o erro aparece no memcpy. Não vejo o que possa editar mais, pois o essencial é isso, e penso que não falta qualquer informação no código postado. Estou a moer um bocado a cabeça com isto, mas não consigo resolver o problema. Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: @Luiz Vieira   nRows é um membro da minha classe, essa parte do código corresponde à função main e não pertence à classe Matrix. Usei nLinhas só para saberem que eram o número de linhas :)  Imagine que a seguir a isso e antes de matrix.putColumn(col,0); eu chamava o construtor da classe passando como argumentos nLinhas e nColunas. :) Obrigado

Comment: Mas, Marco, se `nlinhas` tem um valor diferente de `nCols`, vai dar erro mesmo. Porque fora você aloca `*col` a partir de `nlinhas*sizeof(int)` e dentro você copia com `memcpy(p,Col,nCols)`!

Comment: @Luiz Vieira   PS: já mudei a entrada das colunas para uchar e o erro mantem-se... Ao fazer debug o código dá erro no memcpy. Pois então teria de ter algo do género: memcpy(p,Col,nRows)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Além dos potenciais problemas já mencionados em comentários, você está usando um ponteiro para ponteiro (`**mat`) para manipular os dados, só que ele não foi corretamente inicializado. Então quando você referencia `*mat` a área de memória referenciada não é válida.

Você não precisa usar um ponteiro para ponteiro, basta ter um ponteiro simples para `unsigned char` (e é importante usar o mesmo tipo de dados para evitar problemas). Exemplo de código em C, funcionando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char *mat; // Pointeiro simples, e não ponteiro para ponteiro
int nRows;
int nCols;

void putColumn(unsigned char *Col, int j)
{
    unsigned char *p;
    p = mat + j * nRows; // Aritmética de ponteiro, simples
    memcpy(p, Col, nCols);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Reproduzindo o seu construtor
    nRows = 10;
    nCols = 10;
    mat = (unsigned char*) malloc(nRows * nCols * sizeof(unsigned char)); // Alocação de ponteiro simples

    // Reproduzindo o seu main
    unsigned char *col;
    int nlinhas = 10; // Apesar da variável chamar "nlinhas", esse valor DEVERIA ser o mesmo definido em nCols!
    col = (unsigned char*) malloc(nlinhas * sizeof(unsigned char));

    for(int lin = 0; lin < 10; lin++)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < nlinhas; i++){
            col[i] = 65 + lin; // Para gravar os caracteres ASCII maiúsculos [A, B, C, ...]
        }
        putColumn(col, lin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

O resultado desse exemplo é o seguinte (a variável foi inspecionada via janela de *watch* do debugger do Visual Studio 2012, usando `mat,100` para limitar a exibição da área de memória em 100 bytes):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu mencionei em comentários, apesar de você usar uma variável chamada `nlinhas` para definir o tamanho da nova coluna, ele deveria ser o mesmo da propriedade da classe (`nCols`). Pois se ele for menor (troque para `int nlinhas = 5;` no código de exemplo), você vai deixar dados inválidos na memória:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Nota: E os dados inválidos só estão todos iguais (`ýýýýý«`) porque eu
>   executei a compilação em DEBUG. Em RELEASE o compilador não faz
>   pré-inicialização automática de áreas de memória e ali vai estar o que
>   quer que já estivesse de outras execuções anteriores de programas.

Como em `putColumn` você força a cópia com `nCols`, usar um valor maior do que 10 (nesse exemplo) não vai dar problemas.

Se a sua intenção com o código é permitir a criação de colunas com dados parciais (como no exemplo, com `nlinhas` com valor menor, igual a `5`), é uma boa prática também zerar o total da memória de cada coluna utilizando [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/?kw=memset). Assim você evita que uma coluna mantenha indevidamente dados de uma atualização prévia.

Note também que no seu código original (`main`) você atualizava a nova coluna a partir do índice `1` (e arrays e ponteiros em C/C++ são indexados a partir do `0`):

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= nlinhas; i++){
```

Além de não atualizar a primeira posição de cada coluna, quando você fosse atualizar a última coluna o `<=` ali iria ultrapassar o limite da área de memória reservada para o seu programa, causando também problemas de acesso indevido.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda, excelente explicação :D obrigado mesmo! Resolvido